# Buttons overwriting each other

Tags: java, swing, awt

So my buttons are overwriting each other, instead of all going up North like a tool bar..
I'm trying to get the buttons to go up North if that makes sense. I know my GUI is awful, and I'll rewire it once I get this prototype done.

```
    // panels
    mainPuzzlerPanel = new Panel();
    mainPuzzlerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    puzzlePanel = new Panel();

    //mainPuzzlerPanel.setLayout(null);
    puzzlePanel.setLocation(100, 120);

    // text fields
    debugTxt = new TextArea(null,6,40,1);
    debugTxt.setEditable(false);
    mainPuzzlerPanel.add(debugTxt,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // buttons
    Button newPuzzle = new Button("New Puzzle");
    Button loadImage = new Button("Load Image");
    Button assignLocation = new Button("Assign Location");
    Button assignTimestamp = new Button("Assign Timestamp");
    Button savePuzzle = new Button("Save Puzzle");
    Button clearPuzzleCreator = new Button("Clear");

    newPuzzle.addActionListener(this);
    loadImage.addActionListener(this);
    assignLocation.addActionListener(this);
    assignTimestamp.addActionListener(this);
    savePuzzle.addActionListener(this);
    clearPuzzleCreator.addActionListener(this);

    mainPuzzlerPanel.add(assignLocation,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPuzzlerPanel.add(assignTimestamp,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    mainPuzzlerPanel.add(loadImage,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPuzzlerPanel.add(savePuzzle,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPuzzlerPanel.add(clearPuzzleCreator,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPuzzlerPanel.add(newPuzzle,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPuzzlerPanel.add(puzzlePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(mainPuzzlerPanel, "Controls");

    setSize(1200, 700);
    setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't add all the components BorderLayout.NORTH, makes no sense. Instead, add the JButtons to a JPanel that uses a different layout, say GridLayout, and then add that JPanel BorderLayout.NORTH. But most important -- read a tutorial on how to use the layout managers. It looks like you're guessing at this and that's not an efficient way to learn how to use these complex tools.

Regading,

> I know my GUI is awful, and I'll rewire it once I get this prototype done.

Also not a good plan. It's much easier to write it well the first time through.

e.g.,

```
// after creating all of your JButtons, put them in an array...
JButton[] btnArray = {newPuzzle, loadImage, assignLocation, assignTimestamp, 
        savePuzzle, clearPuzzleCreator};
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0));
for (JButton btn : btnArray) {
  buttonPanel.add(btn);
}
mainPuzzlerPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

---

Edit: Oops, I notice now you're using Buttons and Panels, not JButtons and JPanels. I urge you to change your app to be a Swing app not an AWT app.

---

Layout manager tutorial: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)